# Want to have maximum price and date of each customers in customers table-

Tags: sql-server

http://www.sqlcourse2.com/items_ordered.html

Above is link for table 'Customers'.
I want to have max price of orders of each customer and date of purchase 
I tried like this in SQL Serer but not getting the expected answer 
There shold be unique customerid in my result but m not getting it

```
select customerid, max(price), order_date from items_ordered group by customerid, order_date order by customerid;
```

This is outcome of above query while there should be unique customerid with max(price) and order date.

```
10101   125.00  01-Jul-1999
10101   16.00   02-Jan-2000
10101   88.70   08-Mar-2000
10101   18.30   18-Aug-1999
10101   14.75   30-Dec-1999
10101   58.00   30-Jun-1999
10298   12.50   01-Apr-2000
10298   22.00   01-Dec-1999
10298   33.00   01-Jul-1999
10298   22.38   18-Mar-2000
10298   29.00   19-Sep-1999
10299   1250.00 06-Jul-1999
10299   38.00   18-Jan-2000
10315   8.00    02-Feb-2000
10330   28.00   01-Jan-2000
10330   16.75   19-Apr-2000
10330   28.00   30-Jun-1999
10339   4.50    27-Jul-1999
10410   89.22   28-Oct-1999
10410   192.50  30-Jan-2000
10413   32.00   19-Jan-2000
10438   6.75    01-Nov-1999
10438   8.50    02-Nov-1999
10438   79.99   18-Jan-2000
10439   25.50   14-Aug-1999
10439   88.00   18-Sep-1999
10449   45.00   01-Sep-1999
10449   180.79  13-Aug-1999
10449   380.50  15-Dec-1999
10449   40.00   19-Mar-2000
10449   280.00  22-Dec-1999
10449   4.50    29-Feb-2000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `group by customerid` to get the max `price` for each `customerid` and then join the results to the table:

```
select t.customerid, t.price, t.order_date
from items_ordered t inner join (
  select customerid, max(price) maxprice 
  from items_ordered 
  group by customerid 
) g on g.customerid = t.customerid and g.maxprice = t.price
order by t.customerid
```

Of course if there are more than 1 rows containing the max price, then all of them will be fetched.

Comment: So in my query-select customerid, max(price), order_date from items_ordered group by customerid, order_date order by customerid;   . Both customerid, order_date are acting as composite unique so it's fetching all the prices , right?? i.e for both together (customerid, order_date) as composite, it's going to look for price each time ?

Comment: @nitinkhatri749 is your comment truncated? I do not understand what you want to say.

Comment: I'm saying that sql server is looking for both(customerid and date)columns together as single column and then prices are fetched in my query which I asked for help earlier.

Comment: Yes this query groups by the combination of `customerid, order_date` and fetches the maximum price for each combination.